# Can Logrotate be use in C?

Tags: c, linux, logging, logrotate

I'm a newbie on linux and I was planning to use logrotate so that my log files which generate inside a radio file system, would not getting larger size and cause any memory issue.

but as can see from below, this configuration is set at logrotate.conf file in linux, then I am confused and wonder is it possible to add this thing as a "coding style" in my C files so that it work on my radio which is running Linux system.

The radio don't have this logrotate thing under /etc/logrotate.d path after all. I also unable to install any logrotate or execute the command "man logroate", it tells : no manual entry for 'logrotate'.

```
/var/logs/*.log {
    hourly
    missingok
    rotate 24
    compress
    create
}
```

Can it be called like normal function such as fclose() or fopen() in .C files?

If it can be used in C files, what is the correct way to configure the parameter?

Comment: Logrotate is a separate program which rotates logs for programs which don't rotate their own logs. do you have to use logrotate or do you want to know how to make your program rotate its own logs?

Comment: @user253751 ya I would like to know to how to make my program to rotate its own logs. And i found this logrotate's function is what I wanted, that is why i ask how to implement his logrotate, but seems like it cant help in my C files

Comment: When you think the log file is too big, or too old, you close the log file, and open a new one. You can also use `rename` to rename files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted how logrotate work: It only work with files created  by service/application on host machine.

For example on your linux machine you are running mailing server postfix (base on config you posted):

1. Postfix service filling log file /var/log/postfix.log
2. Logrotate take every hour postfix.log and create compressed file postfix.1
3. Increment number of already existing archive files
4. Logrotate keep 24 compressed files (= 1 day)

In you case you have to setup application logging to save log files and then you can apply logrotate to it.

Logrotate man page can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)